# I have an image and I want to link it with a url. How can I do that? I am using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I have an image and I want to link it with a url. I have used javascript.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLAJL.png)
[after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hkqh.png)
I want to display this image and when I click on it I want some other page to open that has been linked to this img with a url.

how can I do that?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

[Code(I took this from Stack Overflow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViUHn.png)

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function handleClick(){
 const image = new Image ()

image.src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
image.style.width="200px"
image.style.height="200px"
image.alt="Google logo"
image.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.href="https://www.google.com"
})

const element = document.getElementById('image-container')
if(element){
   element.appendChild(image)
}

}
```

```html
<h3> Image will show here </h3>

<div id="image-container"></div>
<button onclick="handleClick()">Show  me </button>
```

I hope this simple snippet will help you.